# Using a boolean to coordinate two threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand the code section below is problematic because the new value of isAlive set in the kill method might not be visible in the thread.

```
public class MyClass extends Thread {
    private boolean isAlive;
    
    public void run() {
        while(isAlive) {
            ....
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        isAlive = false;
    }
}
```

The typical fix is to declare the isAlive variable as volatile.

My question here is that is there any other ways to achieve this without using volatile? Does Java provide other mechanisms to achieve this?

**EDIT: Synchronize the method is also not an option.**

Comment: `synchronized` methods to read and write `isAlive` variable. Also, `AtomicBoolean` but it uses volatile inside

Comment: In most cases, you don't want to manually wrangle threads at all. What's in your infinite loop?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Thanks. Actually, declare the kill method as synchronized is also not an option.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The infinite loop is just an illustration. The operation inside could be invoking kafka consumer to retrieve message from kafka queue. What are the other options to allow one thread to turn on or turn off another thread?

Comment: @ZZZ read this: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/lock-free-multithreading-atomic-operations. The problem with what you are proposing is that primitive values are non-atomic and, therefore, this is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @hfontanez With a boolean, atomicity isn't much of a problem. Visibility on the other hand is.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use `synchronised` or `volatile`?

Comment: Exactly. Not wanting volatile but using a loop in MT context is usually an indicator of a bad design idea. So do you want a ThreadGate, a counter, is the amount of loop runs important, what special relation between the while loop and the kill method exists, so that volatile is not an option?

Comment: Why do you need one thread to reach into another from the outside and change what it does? Why not just code threads to do what, and only what, you want done in the first place so that you don't need some way to reach into a thread from the outside? Also, what is your issue with `volatile`? It's hard to give you an alternative solution when we don't know what your issue is with the obvious, perfect solution you already have.

Comment: @ZZZ it is not enough to declare `kill` as `synchronized`, it covers "write access" only. You also synchronize read access.

Comment: @biziclop Just because it isn't much of a problem it doesn't mean it is OK. It is still not a good practice.

Comment: @hfontanez I think biziclop just meant you can't see a "half-written" boolean. It's not a good practice, but because of the visibility issue, not atomicity.

Comment: @hfontanez What I meant by "not much of a problem" is that In some cases it can be. But in this use case it isn't a problem at all. The lack of visibility is what makes this code fail.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good reason to go for a different option than volatile. Volatile is needed to provide the appropriate happens-before edge between writing and reading; otherwise you have a data-race on your hands and as a consequence the write to the flag might never be seen. E.g. the compiler could hoist the read of the variable out of a loop.

There are cheaper alternative that provide more relaxed ordering guarantees compared to the sequential consistency that volatile provides. E.g. acquire/release or opaque (check out the Atomic classes and the VarHandle). But this should only be used in very rare situations where the ordering constraints reduce performance due to limited compiler optimizations and fences on a hardware level.

Long story short: make the variable volatile because it a simple and very fast solution.

Comment: what you might want to add, is that anything _other_ than `volatile` requires an exceptional amount of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options:

1. Make the shared variable `volatile`.  (This is the simplest way.)
2. Use `synchronized`, either in the form of `synchronized` methods or `synchronized` blocks.  Note that you need to do both reads and writes for the shared variables while holding the (same) mutex.
3. Use one of the classes in `java.util.concurrent` that has a "synchronizing effect"<sup>1</sup>.  Or more precisely, one that you can use to get a *happens before* relationship between the update and subsequent read of the `isAlive` variable.  This will be documented in the respective classes javadocs.

If you don't use one of those options, it is not *guaranteed*<sup>2</sup> that the thread that calls `run()` will see `isAlive` variable change from `true` to `false`.

If you want to understand the deep technical reasons why this is so, read Chapter 17.4 of the Java Language Specification where it specifies the Java Memory Model.  (It will explain what *happens before* means in this context.)

---

<sup>1 - One of the `Lock` classes would be an obvious choice. 

2 - That is to say ... your code may not work 100% reliably on all platforms.  This is the kind of problem where "try it and see" or even extensive testing cannot show conclusively that your code is correct.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The wait/notify mechanism is embedded deep in the heart of the java language, the superclass of classes, has five methods that are the core of the wait/notify mechanism, notify(), notifyAll(), wait(), wait(long), and wait(long, int), all classes in java inherit from Object, in addition, none of these methods can be overridden in a subclass as they are all declared final
here is an example that may help you to understand the concept

```
public class NotifyAndWait {

public List list;
public NofityAndWait() { list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList  ());
public String removeItem() throws InterruptedException {
 synchronized(list) {
 while(list.isEmpty())
 list.wait();
 }
 String item = list.remove(0);  
 return item;
 }
 public void addItem(String item) {
 synchronized(list) {
 list.add(item);
 //after adding, nofity and waiting all thread that the list has changed
 list.notifyAll();
 }
 }
 public static void main(String..args) throws Exception {
 final NotifyAndWait obj = new NotifyAndWait();
 Runnable runA = new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 try {
 String item = enf.removeItem();
 catch(Exception e) {} };
 Runnable runB = new Runnable() {
 public void run() { obj.addItem("Hello"); }
 };
 
 Thread t1 = new Thread(runA, "T1");
 t1.start();  
 Thread.sleep(500);
 Thread t2 = new Thread(runB, "T2");
 t2.start();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, polling a boolean in a while loop as a "kill" control is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Brian Goetz, in "Java Concurrency in Action" has a code example that is very similar to yours, on page 137 (section 7.1 Task Cancellation).

He states that making the boolean `volatile` gives the pattern greater reliability. He has a good description of the mechanism on page 38.

> When a field is declared volatile, the compile and runtime are put on
> notice that this variable is shared and that operations on it should
> not be reordered with other memory operations. Volatile variables are
> not cached in registers or in caches where they are hidden from other
> processors, so a read of a volatile variable always returns the most
> recent write by any thread.

I use volatile booleans and loose coupling as my main method of communication that must occur across threads. AFAIK, `volatile` has a smaller cost than `synchronized` and is the most recommended pattern for this situation.